# How do I save a text string into datastore as blob type in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blob, datastore

Let's come straight to the snippet:

```
class RequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    data = self.request.get('test')
    blob = db.Blob(data) # what should I do here?

    """ Save blob into datastore """

    self.response.out.write("Success")
```

What I'm trying to do is converting "data" to "blob" type and later save it into datastore. I saw the [official sample](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#Blob) used db.Blob() but it didn't work for me (A server error occurs and no "Success" is showed). What should I do to meet my needs? Thanks for your time!

Comment: @voscause I forgot the log... It said "Blob() argument should be str instance, not unicode" and I know what's wrong now. Thanks for the tip :P

Answer (score 0):

The log outputs "TypeError: Blob() argument should be str instance, not unicode". I googled again and found that generally, we should store unicode strings in datastore as db.TextProperty, rather than db.BlobProperty. So The correction should be:

```
class RequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
  text = self.request.get('test')
  """ Don't convert text to blob """
  """ Save text into datastore as db.TextProperty """

  self.response.out.write("Success")
```